The origin of the ご reading of 御
The prefix 御 can be read three different ways in modern Japanese: お, ご and み. I believe み is the original reading, and お maybe comes from 大御, but where does ご come from? I understand it is not actually the 音読み of 御, is it a sound change over time? Do we have any evidence about it?

As you can see in dictionaries, 御{ご} was borrowed from Middle Chinese ngjoH, so it is obviously 音読み. Why would you think otherwise?

I do not understand Middle Chinese, would it not become よ or じょ?

Sino-Japanese g is expected outcome of Middle Chinese syllable-initial ŋ. See table here.

Ah thank you very much, that answers it then! If you would like, you can out this as an answer and I'll use it to close the question.
